# Errors while casting to int/long in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

So I have the following example where I try to convert a float column into string:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame( [[2000000.0,759740220.0]], ['sale_amt', 'total_value'])
display(df)
```

| sale_amt | total_value |
| --- | --- |
| 2000000 | 759740220 |

```
df = df.withColumn("new_col",F.round(F.col("total_value")))
df = df.withColumn("new_col",F.round(F.col("total_value")).cast(StringType()
                                                               ))
```

display(df)

| sale_amt | total_value | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000 | 759740220 | 7.5974022E8 |

The converted string becomes a scientific notation. Is there a way to get the value as plain string instead of this notation.

I seem to get some weird error when using the following transforms on my Dataframe:

```
df_takeone = df_takeone.withColumn("saleDate_dt_mod",F.col("saleDate_dt").cast(LongType()))
df_takeone = df_takeone.withColumn("saleRecordingDate_dt_mod",F.col("saleRecordingDate_dt").cast(LongType()))
    df_takeone = (df_takeone.withColumn('total_value_str_with_comma', F.format_number(F.round(F.col('mailingZipCode_tx')),0))
           .withColumn('total_value_str_wo_commas', F.round(F.col('mailingZipCode_tx')).cast('int').cast('string')))
```

Below is the snippet of the result:
[image]

In the first few rows after casting to int(or long) the value changes. Why would be the reason for this?

Comment: you can cast it to `bigint` before casting it to `string`.

Comment: Ia that the same as LongType?

Comment: yes, they're the same

Comment: What is the value when round function alone is used?

Comment: Just using the round function gives the correct value but when I cast it or format it it changes

Comment: What is the source of dataframe?

Comment: It is after a series of transformations but I saved it as a delta table and then applied the casting and still the value changes.

Comment: Is it happening only for that particular value?

Comment: Not just that value but some others as well. The modified saleDate and saleRecordingDate also differ as you can see from the snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these to convert float data to string.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, format_number, round
df = df.withColumn('total_value_str_with_comma', format_number(round(col('total_value')),0))\
       .withColumn('total_value_str_wo_commas', round(col('total_value')).cast('int').cast('string'))

display(df)
```

| sale_amt | total_value | total_value_str_with_comma | total_value_str_wo_commas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000000 | 759740220 | 759,740,220 | 759740220 |

[image]

Comment: `format_number` already produces a string column. The cast is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format_number() function in PySpark to convert a double column to string without scientific notation:

```
df.withColumn("new_col", format_number("total_value", 1)).show()

+---------+-----------+-------------+
| sale_amt|total_value|      new_col|
+---------+-----------+-------------+
|2000000.0|7.5974022E8|759,740,220.0|
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

The second parameter of format_number represent the number of decimal to be considered when formatting.

Alternatively you can use a udf (this will work without specifying the number of decimals):

```
@udf(returnType=StringType())
def to_string(value):
    return str(value)

df.withColumn("new_col", to_string(col("total_value"))).show()
```